# Is std::regex always locale aware?

Tags: c++, c++11

In the [std::basic_regex](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/basic_regex) reference, one of the flags for the constructor of a `std::regex` is `collate`, which specifies that:

> Character ranges of the form "[a-b]" will be locale sensitive.

This indicates, to me, that `std::regex` is not, by default, (entirely) locale-aware. I can't find anything that claims that it explicitly *is* locale-aware, but then we have `std::regex_traits` which sort of indicates that there is *some* locale-awareness going on.

To what extend is `std::regex` locale-aware?
Is it possible to read a UTF-8 string and store it in a plain `std::string` and just use regex classes such as `[:w:]` and `[:punct:]`? Specifically, `[:w:]` might be a problem. `[:punct:]` is not important.

This is for a C++ library that must work on MacOS (which has UTF-8 locales) and for Windows (which, as far as I can tell, does not).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> one of the flags for the constructor of a `std::regex` is collate, which specifies that:
>
> > Character ranges of the form "[a-b]" will be locale sensitive.

For comprehensive explanation see [Regexp Ranges and Locales: A Long Sad Story](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Ranges-and-Locales.html):

> However, the standard changed the interpretation of range expressions. In the "C" and "POSIX" locales, a range expression like ‘[a-dx-z]’ is still equivalent to ‘[abcdxyz]’, as in ASCII. But outside those locales, the ordering was defined to be based on collation order.
>
> What does that mean? In many locales, ‘A’ and ‘a’ are both less than ‘B’. In other words, these locales sort characters in dictionary order, and ‘[a-dx-z]’ is typically not equivalent to ‘[abcdxyz]’; instead, it might be equivalent to ‘[ABCXYabcdxyz]’, for example.
>
> This point needs to be emphasized: **much literature teaches that you should use ‘[a-z]’ to match a lowercase character. But on systems with non-ASCII locales, this also matches all of the uppercase characters except ‘A’ or ‘Z’!** This was a continuous cause of confusion, even well into the twenty-first century.

---

> This indicates, to me, that `std::regex` is not, by default, (entirely) locale-aware.

Not quite.

In [Modified ECMAScript regular expression grammar](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/ecmascript) it says:

> Character classes
>
> ...
>
> The exact meaning of each of these character class escapes in C++ is defined in terms of the locale-dependent named character classes, and not by explicitly listing the acceptable characters as in ECMAScript.

In other words, it uses the current global locale for character classes like `[:alpha:]`.

---

> Is it possible to read a UTF-8 string and store it in a plain `std::string` and just use regex classes such as `[:w:]` and `[:punct:]`? Specifically, `[:w:]` might be a problem. `[:punct:]` is not important.

There is no knowledge in what encoding the contents of a `std::string` are, they could be in UTF-8 or any other encoding.

You need to decode a `std::string` into `std::wstring`, one way is to use facilities provided by [std::codecvt_utf8](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/codecvt_utf8), and then use `std::wregex`.